# How do I run a gui app from the command line?

Tags: gui, xserver

I need to launch a GUI program from the command line on a machine I have SSH'd into. I don't need to interact with it or see the window, just have it running. When I try and launch it I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-35-163-23223429-46:~/photoscan-pro$ ./photoscan.sh 
photoscan: cannot connect to X server
```

Is there anything I do? I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem is with the script and not with the command you are executing.So what you are doing is the correct way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the script, before the application is launched, add this line:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

This tells the program that it has to run in the DISPLAY with ID :0.0 instead of the terminal where is being called,which (as far as I know) reffers to the TTY7.

In other words, sends it to the graphic environment. You can also use it locally, launching a program in the desktop from a virtual tty. I use it for instance when compiz crashes and there are no menus or icons to restart it:

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0 && compiz --replace
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked! What does this actually do?

Comment: This tells the program that it has to run in the DISPLAY with ID :0.0 instead of the terminal where is being called,which (as far as I know) reffers to the TTY7. In other words, sends it to the graphic environment. You can also use it locally, launching a program in the desktop from a virtual tty. I use it for instance when compiz crashes and there are no menus or icons to restart it: export DISPLAY=:0.0 && compiz --replace

Comment: @darent, you should edit that explanation into the answer.